# Line Break XSL doesn't work

Tags: html, xml, xslt, line-breaks

I have an XML like this:

```
<c id="de-4" level="file">
  <did>
    <unitid label="Cotes">1 DNG 5</unitid>
    <unittitle label="my title">some text1 <lb />some text2<lb />some text3.</unittitle>
    <unitdate label="Date" normal="2014">2014</unitdate>
  </did>
```

And I want to use and convert LB tag -> BR for HTML.
I use an XSL stylesheet to do this:

```
<xsl:template name="cree_cote">
    <td align='left' valign='top' class="titres">
        <xsl:call-template name="_noeud">
            <xsl:with-param name="noeud" select="did/unittitle"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lb">
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<!--  le contenu d'un noeud -->
<xsl:template name="_noeud">
    <xsl:param name="noeud"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$noeud">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$avec_label">
            <xsl:if test="@label">
                <span class='ead_label'>[<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>]</span>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$noeud/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But after converting, I have this:

```
<td valign="top" align="left" class="titres">some text1 some text2some text3.<br><br></td>
```

I don't understand why my `<BR>` are in the end of text.

Comment: Fabrice, there is something wrong with your XML - `<unittitle label="some text1 <lb />some text2<lb />some text3.</unittitle>` isn't well formed. If you fix that and show use your other templates (especially the one for `unittitle`) we can probably be helpful :)

Comment: That templates is fine, you need to show the other templates as well, they need to use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to make sure the child nodes like the `lb` elements are processed and are processed in document order.

Comment: Nic, yes, in Stack, i've made a mistake. it's fixed in my post now.
Martin, i've 1470 lines of my XSL. I can't paste all here, though?

Comment: Well, isolate the problem and then post the context, we need to see any templates for `unittitle` and `did` elements. Basically if you use an approach like `<xsl:template match="unittitle"><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></xsl:template>` then the input order should be preserved in the output order, meaning the `br` elements appear in place of `lb` elements.

Comment: I've add more details from my XSL in my post. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have access to your whole XSLT, it's hard to give you the cleanest recommendation, but the reason that your `lb`s are being output after the text is because you are outputting the `text()` before applying templates to the child nodes!

Please give this a try:

```
<!--  le contenu d'un noeud -->
<xsl:template name="_noeud">
    <xsl:param name="noeud"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$noeud">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$avec_label and @label">
            <span class='ead_label'>[<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>]</span>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can watch my XSL and XML here :
http://jsfiddle.net/Bd9Au/1/
Sorry, I don't know all websites to publish this code for you.

Comment: @user3766698 I'm afraid I can't dig through an XSLT that big for you, but does the above work?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xsl:template name="cree_cote">
    <td align='left' valign='top' class="titres">
        <xsl:call-template name="_noeud">
            <xsl:with-param name="noeud" select="did/unittitle"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template name="cree_cote">
    <td align='left' valign='top' class="titres">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="did/unittitle"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

then change

```
<xsl:template name="_noeud">
    <xsl:param name="noeud"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$noeud">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$avec_label">
            <xsl:if test="@label">
                <span class='ead_label'>[<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>]</span>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$noeud/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="did/unittitle">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="$avec_label and @label">
    <span class="ead_label">[xsl:value-of select="@label"/>]</span>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And of course keep your template for `lb` elements.